# Why is rolling back not rate limited?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting, rollbacks

I just managed to roll [this question back about 20 times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/246752/revisions), in 3 minutes:

[image]

In fact, the only reason I couldn't do more was the IP address "unusual number of requests" limit:

[image]

Almost everything else I try to do has some sort of rate limit:

[image]

But this doesn't. Is there any reason why it doesn't? I could really, really bug someone with a *lot* of notifications about their post.

Comment: Why exactly did you do this?

Comment: @bluefeet testing stuff is OK, but not on "live" posts, better be done in the sandbox.

Comment: @ShadowWizard My thought was to be a pain

Comment: Yep, Tim ^^^, in Sandbox ;)

Comment: @bluefeet nah, this is reserved for nicael :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard I call shenanigans with both of them

Comment: @shadow Yeah, sorry, completely forgot about sandbox. I did pick a non up voted question of mine on purpose. And yeah, @nicael is the one who does it to be a pain :P `

Comment: @bluefeet honestly didn't mean to - I'd noticed it a while ago, and wanted to bring it to meta. 30 was needed to get the IP limit. Apologies.

Comment: @Tim Just giving you a hard time. :)

Comment: come to sandbox, made a discovery! (accept rate)